# Why is the chemical formula for ethanoic acid CH3COOH and not C2H4O2?

Tags: structural-formula

Why does the hydrogen ion move to the front of the formula and not to the subscript of the H already in the formula?

Answer (score -1):

The first one is preferred since its makes it easy to see that it has a carboxyl group and a methyl group, so its easier to draw the Lewis structure and figure out the molecule's properties. For example, from the first formula one can see that it is an acid. However, its more difficult to figure that out from the second one.

Comment: I would not call either formula *preferred;* see my answer to the duplicate question.